# Connect ESP8266 to open network using AT commands

Tags: networking, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

We have an Arduino Uno connected to an ESP8266 and a bunch of other devices. We are using the ESP8266 as a WiFi connector (obviously) to send data to REST API.

Our problem is that we have to use an open network, and there is no AT-* command that does "connect to SSID without password".

We have considered using the `CWJAP` command, passing password as "", but have failed -- that may be because of a dumb AP we used (TPLINK), but we are wondering if this is the right approach (sending nothing vs nothing being sent dilemma).

Have you perhaps had any success with using such a configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper way to connect to open network using `AT` commands is to provide:

```
AT+CWJAP=ssid,password
```

for example:

```
AT+CWJAP="Johns Network", ""
```

Which would be a string:

```
"AT+CWJAP=\"Johns Network\",\"\"".
```